# Pandas - Indexing by not in index

Tags: pandas, indexing

Googled around a bit and couldn't seem to find anything on this.

Is there an option to access data in a pandas data frame using "not index"?
So something like

```
df_index = asdf = pandas.MultiIndex(levels=[
['2014-10-19', '2014-10-20', '2014-10-21', '2014-10-22', '2014-10-30'],
[u'after_work', u'all_day', u'breakfast', u'lunch', u'mid_evening']],
labels=[[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
[4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 0, 1, 3, 4]],
names=[u'start_date', u'time_group'])
```

And then I would like to be able to call the following to get everything not in `df_index`

```
df.ix[~df_index]
```

I know you can do it for logical indexing within pandas. Just curious if I could do it using an Index Object

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use `df.drop(df_index, errors="ignore")`.

Comment: Awesome, great thinking. Thanks!